# How to select multiple app icons in Launchpad to move them?

Tags: macos, mac, launchpad

Is it possible to select more than one app icon at a time in Launchpad and then drag them to a folder?

Comment: This is akin to something you can't unsee - it just seems like there should be a way to get at multiple selection, but the simple finder interaction seems to be unchangeable so far - even with code modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of operation doesn't seem to be available. Based on how the interaction between the waggling icons and the gui is, I don't even think it would be possible with a reasonable usability.

Apple has chosen to reproduce the same feel as it is on iOS devices so that everybody familiar with that - extremely easy, btw - workflow can achieve the same in Lion.

Comment: My assessment too. However, it took me about an hour to rearrange my Launchpad icons into any semblance of the order and groupings I wanted them in, so Apple definitely have work to do here.

Comment: Please remember that this is version 1.0 of Lion. I guess that based on user feedback that now comes from a much wider spectrum of people using the system, Apple will have the input required to tweak the systems that at the moment don't work as good as users expect them to work.

Comment: @scottishwildcat - ditto on the time to re-arrange my Launchpad.

Comment: @mwidmann - I appreciate Apple blurring the lines between OS X and iOS as long as they don't forget that most OS X devices (i.e. MBPs) still use a mouse and that can still be a good thing.

Comment: Without having numbers at hand I'm pretty sure that most of the devices pointing at Lion are Trackpads integrated into a MacBook. And the feel of such devices is much more like a touchscreen device than the one of a mouse. The main issue imo is that Apple believes that people's minds can fill the gap between the content being directly under the tip of the finger and the content being disconnected. I'm not sure if this will work out in the end, we'll see.

Comment: Agreed. If getting use to the new "natural" scroll is any indication, it will take some time, but will be worth it in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple selection is not implemented in LaunchPad. A work around: Drag individual icons into a folder (to make the first folder drag an icon over another and drop). Then move the folder to the new location and unpack it.